# Request over multiple schemas with Hibernate Criteria Api

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

As we have a multitenant database, it is not an option to specify the schema name in the @Table definition.
The entity manager used when building the criteria request is therefore bound to a specific schema.

How one would request multiple schemas using criteria API ? Is it even possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Mat, were you able to find a solution? I am looking for a solution for the same problem.

Comment: Nope, but we used a simple trick : define a view in public schema that accesses all tenants. Hibernate is able to use that view.